# How to display a list of the folders?

Tags: php

I have a folder with subfolders, I see only subfolders?

That's what I use:

```
if ($dir = opendir('templates')) {
    $blacklist = array('.', '..');
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {
        if (!in_array($file, $blacklist)) {
            echo $file.'<br>';
        }
    }
    closedir($dir);
}
```

In the destination folder is two folders and one image.

That's what I get:[image]

Comment: I'm not clear what the problem is? What would you like to achieve?

Comment: What do you _expect_ to get? You are reading the contents of `templates/` and it sounds like you are getting all three contents displayed. (2 dirs, 1 file)

Comment: I want see only subfolders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use is_dir() and is_file()

```
if ($dir = opendir('templates')) {
    $blacklist = array('.', '..');
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {
        if (!in_array($file, $blacklist)) {
            if (is_dir($file)){
            echo $file.'<br>';
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($dir);
}
```